# Is SOP equal to the negation of POS of the same truth table?

Tags: boolean, truthtable

Is the Sum Of Product equal to the negation of Product Of Sum of the same truth table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a research and found that SOP of a truth table is equal to the POS of the same truth table. So, If I get the negation of a SOP, it is equal to the negation of POS of same table.